# A project profile was not found error in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework. I installed it and created a project using zf create project. Now I am not able to add action using zf create action add Index since am getting an error message 'A project profile was not found' can someone please help? http://www.leoganda.net/solving-zend-framework-error-an-error-has-occurred-a-project-profile-was-not-found/ the steps mentioned in this link is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this tutorial and was able to setup ZF

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Change you dir to project dir.

On Windows:

```
cd disk:\path\project
zf create action
```

On Linux/Mac OS (you must has zf.sh in you PATH variable!):

```
cd /path/project
zf create action
```

If this don't help:

Did you copy library/Zend to you project?

Comment: thank you for your help. I have done all these but still its not working. actually I copied the ZendFramework folder to php folder and changed the ini file as include_path = ".;F:\New folder\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library" and exectued the .bat file and opend the shell and created a project in htdocs as zf create project abcd and copied the zend folder from the library folder to the library folder of the abcd. now I opend the abcd folder in the shell as 'cd abcd'. I wrote zf create action add Index in shell but got the error message A project profile was not found

Answer (score 0):

i created an alias

```
alias zf='/path/to/zendframework/bin/zf.sh'
```

and now it work perfectly from the root of the project